# What does it usually mean when an employer let you go early for Trial shift?

Tags: hiring-process

So I had a trial shift as a waiter this morning. The trial shift lasted about an hour and 20 minutes. It wasn't busy at time and I was told that they're gonna let me go early because it's not busy and this trial shift is just for me to see what the restaurant is like and how things work.
They said they're going to get back to me at the end of the week as there'll be a few more people coming in for trial shift.

So is it possible that my trial shift went downhill? Perhaps I didn't give them a good impression and that's why they decided to let me go early?

Comment: It's almost certainly a sign of the restaurant being busy and nothing else.

Comment: For a restaurant this is a tricky answer as it is quite normal to send staff home when it's not busy so it could have nothing to do with your actions.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as a former server, this isn't bad. Restaurants operate in a much different fashion than other businesses. When you go home is relative to the amount of business. My schedule only listed in-times and not out-times. I never knew exactly when I'd be off. Sometimes I would be out early if we were slow, sometimes I stayed as late as the closing servers (along with two or three others).

The trial shift could be likened to a technical interview or a programming exercise. Think of it as a technical screening. They are looking for new wait-staff that either have experience or raw talent that can be honed into the type of employee they are looking for. Take what they said at face value. I would say wait until Thursday before you call them and see where they stand in the interview process. Also, ask for the manager that was on duty during your trial shift if they are available. If not, ask for the store manager.

When you do call them, make sure it is on their down time. Down time depends on the type of restaurant, but for a dinner-heavy service, I would say 2:00 - 3:00 PM is a good time frame. That makes sure that they are fully out of any lunch rush and well ahead of any dinner rush.

Answer (score 2):

They probably saw what they needed to see good or bad.

If you waited more than 3 tables they got to see how you work.

If it went poorly you most likely would have had some signs. 
Did they correct you in front of the customer or add to what you said? 
If they said "I will take the desert order" that is probably a bad sign.

If they let you wait the tables beginning to end with no or little correction it probably went OK.

If they had no intention of hiring you they probably would have told you.